# What is the difference between "abc//def//ghi" and "abc/def/ghi" while specifying a URL

Tags: url, path, relative-path

What is the difference between
    "abc//def//ghi" 
and 
    "abc/def/ghi"
while specifying a URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a difference. If you put two slashes (//) it will just redirect to the webpage with one slash (/). However, two slashes are commonly used after the http://, then any necessary slashes (to indicate directories/folders, etc) need only one.